# How to use bootstrap scss media query and mixins to multiple components scss files in React JS files

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, scss-mixins

Bootstrap 5 SCSS file loading multiple times in ReactJS project due to importing `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` bootstrap in all components scss file.

I have multiple components files with their own scss files like dashboard.tsx - dashboard.scss, header.tsx - header.scss , sidebar.tsx - sidebar.scss etc...

I cannot use bootstrap media queries without importing `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` in each component's scss files. Due to this application loading bootstrap multiple times.[screenshot of styles loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMm1a.png)